# Problems Connecting Asus Transformer TF101 to Mac OS X 10.92

Tags: usb, google-maps, device-firmware, macos

Please bear with me if this is an insipid question, but I am not able to connect my Asus tablet to my Mac. It has been recommended that I go and download the USB drivers for the tablet [here](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/28/1/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/8/). Seemed easy enough. WRONG! USB drivers are well supported for Windows, but not Mac or Linux (odd). There is a third party application that Asus says you need to install called Splashtop Streamer for Windows or Mac in order to move forward with the installation of the drivers.

I gave that the old college try and, much to my chagrin, Splashtop Streamer does not seem to have clear instruction on how to configure their product. I left a comment on one of their [pages](https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/entries/21742727-Error-message-Your-6783-port-is-not-reachable?page=1#post_25461766) that discussed a error "Your 6783 port is not reachable", which seemed to be adversely affecting my completion of the installation process.

In summary, I am dead in the water. I can not install USB drivers in order to load my app onto my device to test. I am trying to test a Google Map App using V2 of the API. Apparently, the Eclipse and the Android Studio emulators to not render the new Google Maps API. So, i need to ship the app to a device.

Must I really buy a new one? Please ponder and grant me any wisdom you might have?
Also, if you think this question was useful, please give it vote. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I can't give you a solution to your software problem (due to the fact that I haven't used a mac in a while) but I can give some suggestions on how to move forward from your current state (as far as development goes).

There are two situations you might be in, I have possible solutions for both:

Situation 1: You don't need the drivers

-As [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) article states "If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works"
Meaning no drivers are needed. But there is still other things to be done (instructions in article)

Situation 2: USB isn't going to work/I don't know what the problem with USB is.

Short Term Solution: package up your app in a .apk and throw that on your device.

Long Term Solution: Look into connecting to your device over your network, from a quick glance this looks to be a good place to start: [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Let me know how it goes, and if you have any questions.

Comment: To your short-term solution, how can you place an App on a device if you can not connect to it? One would have to use a VM, place the apk file on the Windows VM and hope that the device will get picked up by the Windows VM. Is that what you mean, because that will be Dev painful.

Comment: The link you gave in your "Long Term Solution" makes suggestion for a rooted device. My device is not rooted as I have not found clear explanations for the TF101. Thank you for your suggestions though.

Comment: For the apk you can just email it yourself or use dropbox/drive/something similar

Comment: Thanks @Colin your answer actually ended up being quite helpful. Believe it or not, when i updated things they started working so i suspect that fundamentally, you were correct. Sorry it took so long to acknowledge.